# MPAndroidChart: Hide 0 value labels in a stacked bar chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to show a stacked bar chart containing two sets of data (Income and Expenditure). I'm having an issue when the value is 0 the label overlap other x axis values.

In the case of the screenshot you can see that the bars which have values have overlapping values for the following dates: 14/4, 15/4 and 16/4.

How can I hide the 0 values to stop the overlapping issue?[image: Stacked bar chart graph]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `IValueFormatter` interface.

Example:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {

        if(value > 0) {
            return mFormat.format(value);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Set it for the chart-data:

```
barData.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

Also check the [**documentation**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface).